# Elastic Beanstalk reports 5xx errors even though instances are in perfect health

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, locust

I need to set up an api application for gathering event data to be used in a recommendation engine. This is my setup:

- Elastic Beanstalk env with a load balancer and autoscaling group.
- I have 2x t2.medium instances running behind a load balancer.
- EBS configuration is 64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03 v2.1.1 running Tomcat 8 Java 8
- Additionally I have 8x t2.micro instances that I use for high-load testing the api, sending thousands of requests/sec to be handled by the api.
- Im using Locust (http://locust.io/) as my load testing tool.
- Each t2.micro instance that is run by Locust can send up to about 500req/sec

Everything works fine while the reqs/sec are below 1000, maybe 1200. Once over that, my load balancer reports that some of the instances behind it are reporting 5xx errors (attached). I've also tried with 4 instances behind the load balancer, and although things start out well with up to 3000req/sec, soon after, the ebs health tool and Locust both report 503s and 504s, while all of the instances are in perfect health according to the actual numbers in the ebs Health Overview, showing only 10%-20% CPU utilization.

Is there smth I'm missing in configuring the env? It seems like no matter how many machines I have behind the load balancer, the env handles no more than 1000-2000 requests per second.

[image]

---

EDIT:
Now I know for sure that it's the ELB that is causing the problems, not the instances.

I ran a load test with 10 simulated users. Each user sends about 1req/sec and the load increases by 10 users/sec to 4000 users, which should equal to about 4000req/sec. Still it doesn't seem to like any request rate over 3.5k req/sec (**attachment1**).

As you can see from **attachment2**, the 4 instances behind the load balancer are in perfect health, but I still keep getting 503 errors. It's just the load balancer itself causing problems. Look how SurgeQueueLength and SpilloverCount increase rapidly at some point. (**attachment3**) I'm trying to figure out why.

Also I completely removed the load balancer and tested with just one instance alone. It can handle up to about 3k req/sec. (**attachment4** and **attachment5**), so it's definitely the load balancer.

Maybe I'm missing some crucial limit that load balancers have by default, like the queue size of 1024? What is normal handle rate for 1 load balancer? Should I be adding more load balancers? Could it be related to availability zones? ELB listeners from one zone are trying to route to instances from a different zone?

attachment1:
[image]

attachment2:
[image]

attachment3:
[image]

attachment4:
[image]

attachment5:
[image]

---

UPDATE:
Cross zone load balancing is enabled

---

UPDATE:
maybe this helps more:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The message says that "9.8 % of the requests to the ELB are failing with HTTP 5xx (6 minutes ago)". This does not mean that your instances are not returning HTTP 5xx responses. The requests are failing at the ELB itself. This can happen when your backend instances are at capacity (e.g. connections are saturated and they are rejecting connections to the ELB).

Your requests are spilling over at the ELB. They never make it to the instance. If they were failing at the EC2 instances then the cause would be different and data for the environment would match the data for the instances.

Also note that the cause says that this was the state "6 minutes ago". Elastic Beanstalk multiple data sources - one is the data coming from the instance which shows the requests per second and HTTP status codes in the table shown. Another data source is cloudwatch metrics for your ELB. Since cloudwatch metrics for ELB are 1 minute, this data is slightly delayed and the cause tells you how old the information is.

Comment: hi Rohit. thanks for ansering. I added to my post. take a look.

Comment: Can you try turning on CrossZone load balancing for your environment? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.elb.html

Comment: hmm ... the surge queue length is high and that is causing the spike. per the definition of surge queue metric your backend instances are rejecting connections to the load balancer.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/10/28/elastic-load-balancing-adds-new-cloudwatch-metrics/

"Surge Queue Length: the number of requests queued by the load balancer, awaiting a back-end instance to accept connections and process the request. "

Comment: For the single instance case are you still routing through the load balancer or are you directly connecting to the instance? Can you see how many connections are open on the backend instances using netstat?

Comment: I haven't set up ssh into the instance itself. ill do that next. but when using just 1 instance, it's with no load balancer.  by itself, the instance allows up to 3000k req/sec. after that it starts degrading in health with high CPU utilization.

Comment: I also have "ebs optimized: off"

Comment: hey @rohit what command did you what me to run exactly. im getting overwhelmed by all the options in netstats. sorry, I've barely used netstats before. My requests are on http port 80. did you want me to run the command while im flooding or when the servers are quiet?

Comment: I was suggesting you run `netstat -na | grep ESTABLISHED` to see how many connections are being used on your EC2 instances while you are seeing spillovers. Also check the `ulimit` for your process using `cat /proc/<pid>/limits`. Try the pid of both the nginx/httpd proxy and your backend application. May be you are running oout of file handles. You may want to tweak that.